# problems with haskell code understanding

Tags: haskell

'm a student, just starting working with Haskell and have problems with part of code. I does not understand how this code works. Can anyone explain my how it worked?

```
check :: String -> Bool
check = check' [] where
    check' []       []       = True
    check' _        []       = False
    check' x       ('(':xs) = check' ('(':x) xs
    check' ('(':x) (')':xs) = check' x xs
    check' _        (')':xs) = False
    check' x       (_  :xs) = check' x xs
```

Comment: Which part of it don't you understand? Do you know what the function is supposed to do? Are you familiar with Haskell syntax?

Comment: I doesn't understand how this program checking brackets balance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This first parameter of `check'` function serves as a stack to count the opened brackets. Every time it encounters an opening bracket, it appends it to the stack and proceeds with the rest of the input line:

```
check' x ('(':xs) = check' ('(':x) xs
```

Then, when it encounters a closing bracket, it pops an opening bracket and proceeds:

```
check' ('(':x) (')':xs) = check' x xs
```

But if there is a closing bracket and no opening ones left in the stack, it fails:

```
check' _ (')':xs) = False
```

Also, if the line is over, and unclosed brackets remain, fail:

```
check' _ []       = False
```

By default, the stack is empty. The rest are the obvious boundary cases.